# Deserializing XML attributes from the same Xml element c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-parsing, xml-deserialization

I want to deseralize the following XML in C#

```
<Configuration>
    <Parameters>
        <Parameter AttrName1 = "AttrValue1"/>
        <Parameter AttrName2 = "AttrValue2"/>
        <Parameter AttrName3 = "AttrValue3"/>
    </Parameters>
</Configuration>
```

I am having trouble because Attributes names and values are all differents for the same value.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Paste XML as Classes, just make that valid xml first

Comment: That Xml is my input. I would need to read, update then probably save.

Comment: Out of interest why do you need three different parameter names. They could all be called AttrName for example. Just curious. 

Answer (score 2):

You can use these classes to serialize/deserialize your xml. Note this is a feature in VS: [Paste XML as Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/generating-data-type-classes-from-xml)

```
// NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Configuration
{

    private ConfigurationParameter[] parametersField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Parameter", IsNullable = false)]
    public ConfigurationParameter[] Parameters
    {
        get
        {
            return this.parametersField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.parametersField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ConfigurationParameter
{

    private string attrName1Field;

    private string attrName2Field;

    private string attrName3Field;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string AttrName1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.attrName1Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.attrName1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string AttrName2
    {
        get
        {
            return this.attrName2Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.attrName2Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string AttrName3
    {
        get
        {
            return this.attrName3Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.attrName3Field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never knew about that feature. I wrote mine manually. I am going to see if I can use this to compare the results in my C# project with my own code..